# Are there any slicers that use anti-aliasing (such as FXAA) for higher quality thumbnail generation?

Tags: slicing, thumbnail

I use the [Cura Thumbnails plugin](https://plugins.octoprint.org/plugins/UltimakerFormatPackage/) to create and embed thumbnails in my G-code to view them using OctoPrint or my printer LCD. However, I recently found much higher quality Thumbnails that were generated using [fast approximate anti-aliasing (FXAA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_approximate_anti-aliasing). I was wondering if there is a way to enable or use another tool (slicer) to embed higher-quality thumbnails that were generated using anti-aliasing methods such as FXAA. For example, as generated by the tool [unlimitedbacon/stl-thumb](https://github.com/unlimitedbacon/stl-thumb/releases) as shown below:

#### An example of thumbnails generated with that tool:

[image: example of generated thumbnails with st-thumb tool]

#### An example of a thumbnail generated without and with FXAA:

[image: example of thumbnail generated without FXAA and with FXAA]

Comment: No need of complex antialiasing, they could simply render at 4x the size and downsample with bicubic/lanczos.

Comment: I suppose so but I suppose that would take much more unnecessary compute power compared to using hardware accelerated FXAA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of May 2023, Cura is working on it as described in [this Github issue Ultimaker/Cura/issues/7447](https://github.com/Ultimaker/Cura/issues/7447). One [user suggests](https://github.com/Ultimaker/Cura/issues/7447#issuecomment-1056931716) the use of the spatial anti-aliasing method [supersampling anti-aliasing (SSAA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersampling) instead.